# how to prevent form height increase on every click in Internet Explorer 9 in jqGrid

Tags: css, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, jqgrid, internet-explorer-9

In IE9, every click in certain place in form increases form height.
I used Oleg jqGrid sample for create testcase.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open page below in Internet Explorer 9
2. Click in first row in text 'clicking me increases form height' so that it becomes yellow
3. click in view record button in lower left corner
4. click in 'clicking me increases form height' text in form

Observed:

Every click increases form height in Internet Explorer 9.
How to fix this ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>how to center jqGrid popup modal window?</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.7.2/src/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.7.2/src/css/jquery.searchFilter.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.7.2/src/css/ui.multiselect.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.7.2/src/ui.multiselect.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.7.2/src/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.7.2/src/grid.base.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.7.2/src/grid.common.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.7.2/src/grid.formedit.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.7.2/src/grid.inlinedit.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.7.2/src/grid.custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.7.2/src/jquery.fmatter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.7.2/src/jquery.searchFilter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.7.2/src/grid.jqueryui.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.7.2/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.7.2/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var mydata = [
                {id:"2",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"clicking me increases form height clicking me increases form height test2 sdfsdfsd dfksdfkj sdfjksdfjk sdsdl sdklfsdjklf dsflsdl sdlfsdfklj lsdlf sdlsdfklsdjlk sdfsdlfkjsd sflsdfkjsdfs sdfsjdfklsdklfj fsdjflsdfj",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}
            ];
            var grid = $("#list");
            grid.jqGrid({
                data: mydata,
                datatype: "local",
                colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
                colModel:[
                    {name:'id',index:'id', key: true, width:70, sorttype:"int"},
                    {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date", editable: true},
                    {name:'name',index:'name', width:100, editable: true, edittype: 'textarea',
wrap: 'on',
editoptions: {                  wrap : "on",
                                style : "width:30px"
}
},
                    {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float", editable: true},
                    {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float", editable: true},
                    {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float", editable: true},
                    {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}
                ],
                pager:'#pager',
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
                sortname: 'id',
                sortorder: 'asc',
                viewrecords: true,
                height: "100%",
                caption: "Custom Navigation to Top Toolbar"
            });
            grid.jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{add:false,del:false,search:false,refresh:false, edit: false, view: true},
                        { beforeShowForm: function(form) {
                             // "editmodlist"
                             var dlgDiv = $("#editmod" + grid[0].id);
                             var parentDiv = dlgDiv.parent();
                             var dlgWidth = dlgDiv.width();
                             var parentWidth = parentDiv.width();
                             var dlgHeight = dlgDiv.height();
                             var parentHeight = parentDiv.height();
                             // TODO: change parentWidth and parentHeight in case of the grid
                             //       is larger as the browser window
                             dlgDiv[0].style.top = Math.round((parentHeight-dlgHeight)/2) + "px";
                             dlgDiv[0].style.left = Math.round((parentWidth-dlgWidth)/2) + "px";
                          }
                        });
        });
    //]]>
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<table id="list"><tbody><tr><td/></tr></tbody></table>
<div id="pager"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes Andrus, it's exactly the same IE9 bug which reference I posted you today: [this bug report](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/heightauto-works-wrong-in-ie-height100-works-correct/#p22557). The bug was fixed in the main grid in jqGrid 4.0, but you found one more place where exactly the same problem exist.

To fix the problem I suggest the following. In the View form where the error take place we test whether the value of height of the form is `'auto'` and the code run under IE9. In the case we will change the setting `height: 'auto'` to `height: '100%'`:

```
grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {view: true}, {}, {}, {}, {},
    {
        beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
            if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.slice(0,3) === '9.0' &&
                    $form[0].style.height === 'auto') {
                $form[0].style.height = '100%';
            }
        }});
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/IE9BugInForm.htm) demonstrate the bug fix ([here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/IE9BugInForm0.htm) one can test the bug in IE).

**UPDATED**: I looked in the source code of [viewGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#viewgridrow) and found more easy workaround. One should just use (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/IE9BugInForm1.htm))

```
{ dataheight: '100%' }
```

setting instead of default `dataheight: 'auto'` setting. By the way I didn't found in the code of jqGrid any place where the `height` parameter will be used. It seems, that one should now use `dataheight` parameter instead.

If I would find enough time I would post the bug to Microsoft as the official support request. My previous expiration was always the same: MS confirmed the bug as confirmed that my request was for free: I don't have to pay for the request. On the other side to create the clear example and to describe the problem one need time. So I should invest my time and "for free". Moreover the bug will be typically not fixed in the current product (IE9) and will be *probably* fixed in the next version of IE (IE10). In such situation the writing of the bug reports is not really attractive. :-)

Comment: Thank you. Excellent. You can add testcase from this question to MS bug report, it is completely standalone.

Comment: there is similar issue in IE9: after inline edit is completed in jqgrid, clicking in some other row is ignored: inline editing does not start anymore. This occurs especially if jqgrid inline edit increases editable row height (multi line textarea is rendered) but also occurs with single row editing. I posted it in comment to your reply is SO but havent got any response.  Sometimes after comment is posted in stackoverflow clicking edit link in comment is ignored. In both cases page refresh is required to restore click behaviour, maybe this is related. How to fix those issues?

Comment: @Andrus: I answer many questions and can forget about one or other comment. Moreover I do my main job too. :-) About your second question: I am not sure that i understand you correct. I see only that you have some problem in some situation with inline editing in case of usage large multi-line textarea. I can imagine this, I believe you that such problem exist, but what is your question? How you imagine to fix the problem? One should be able at least to reproduce it and before all to have clear description of the problem.